# How to install gopenvpn?

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn

How do i install gopenvpn and configure it in `ubuntu 11.10 x64`?
I managed to build it from source code, but when i start it i get the following

`No OpenVPN configuration files were found in /etc/openvpn`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
No OpenVPN configuration files were found in /etc/openvpn
```

The above output means there is no server.conf or client.conf in /etc/openvpn directory.
You have to manually copy config file and edit it.
ex:

```
sudo cp /usr/share/doc/openvpn/examples/sample-config-files/server.conf.gz /etc/openvpn/
```

check here
https://help.ubuntu.com/11.10/serverguide/openvpn.html

Answer (score 0):

Well finally to fix this error you need to provide openvpn with your `*.ovpn` file and the certificate file. Just put them into `/etc/openvpn`.
Then you should use something like `dconf-editor` to add `gopenvpn` to the list of permitted applications in tray. Open `dconf-editor` and go to `Desktop -> Unity`. Then add `gopenvpn` to the list. That fixes the issue with the error message.